# Bypassing Password Verify Function

Tags: oracle, password

I am considering making a recommendation to enforce a password verify function that will not allow users to change their own passwords.  My understanding of the PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION in Oracle is that the function only restricts the password criteria when the user changes his or her own password.  It would not restrict a privileged user from changing someone else's password or a third party IAM software from changing the password, but I cannot find that expressly documented.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION is used, even when a privileged user changes another user's password, see below.

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlpwdmg.sql
SQL> create user u1 identified by Oracle123#;

User created.

SQL> select profile from dba_users where username = 'U1';

PROFILE
------------------------------
DEFAULT

SQL> select limit from dba_profiles where profile = 'DEFAULT' and resource_name = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';

LIMIT
----------------------------------------
VERIFY_FUNCTION_11G

SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"

SQL> alter user u1 identified by 1;
alter user u1 identified by 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20001: Password length less than 8
```

Comment: Unless the privileged user changes the user's password via `VALUES`.

Comment: A priviliged user could also set the profile's PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION  to NULL, then update the user's password, then set the profile back again.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE` the user using `BY VALUES`:

```
CREATE USER "PEPITO" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '7D7BA78DE23FF6'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
```

This will bypass any password function

Answer (score -1):

ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20001: Password length less than 16

If you are getting such a error, please  follow the below.

1. change the password with correct 16 character,will satisfy the password policy.
2. change the profile from default to user defined profile/or create new profile
   alter user  profile .
3. now change the password as u wish, which not needed to full fill the password policy.
4. now change the profile  back to default.